# How to block only one mouse button?

Tags: python, pynput

The middle button on my mouse sometimes clicks several times when I click it once. My mouse is expensive and I like it, so I decided to fix it with a program.
When I release the middle button, I'd like to freeze it for 0.1 seconds without freezing the other buttons.

I tried to block with the `supress=True` flag in `pynput` library, and then sending button for windows, but this doesn't work.

```
from pynput.mouse import Button, Controller, Listener
import time

mouse = Controller()


class BlockMiddle:
    def __init__(self):
        self.start = time.time()
        with Listener(on_click=self.on_click, on_move=self.on_move,
                      suppress=True
                      ) as listener:
            listener.join()

    def on_click(self, x, y, button, pressed):
        if button == Button.left:
            if pressed:
                mouse.press(Button.left)
            else:
                mouse.release(Button.left)
        if button == Button.right:
            if pressed:
                mouse.press(Button.right)
            else:
                mouse.release(Button.right)
        if button == Button.middle:
            if pressed:
                if time.time() - self.start > 0.1:
                    mouse.press(Button.middle)
            else:
                mouse.release(Button.middle)
                self.start = time.time()
        if button == Button.x1:
            if pressed:
                mouse.press(Button.x1)
            else:
                mouse.release(Button.x1)
        if button == Button.x2:
            if pressed:
                mouse.press(Button.x2)
            else:
                mouse.release(Button.x2)

    def on_move(self, x, y):
        mouse.position = (x, y)

block = BlockMiddle()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I solved my problem.

```
from pynput.mouse import Button, Controller, Listener
import time

mouse = Controller()


class BlockMiddle:
    def __init__(self):
        self.start = time.time()
        self.listener = Listener(
                on_click=self.on_click,
                on_move=self.on_move,
                on_scroll=self.on_scroll,
                suppress=False
                )
        with self.listener as l:
            l.join()

    def on_click(self, x, y, button, pressed):
        self.listener._suppress = False
        if not button == Button.middle:
            return
        if time.time() - self.start < 0.1:
            self.listener._suppress = True
        if not pressed:
            self.start = time.time()
            self.listener._suppress = False

    def on_move(self, x, y):
        self.listener._suppress = False

    def on_scroll(self, x, y, dx, dy):
        self.listener._suppress = False


block = BlockMiddle()
```